# DatabaseContext.Set<T> not using the where clause in Sql

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-6

I'm perhaps using the wrong method to instigate a query. This is EF6 with Sql Server backend. I have:

```
public IEnumerable<T> Select(string sessionId, Func<T, bool> predicate = null)
{
  using (var databaseContext = new DatabaseContext())
  {
    var list = databaseContext.Set<T>().Where(predicate ?? (x => true)).AsQueryable<T>().ToList();
    list.ForEach(o => o.SessionId = sessionId);
    return list;
  }
}
```

If I call it with `Select('sdfsdf', o => o.Category == 'Save Pewdiepie')`, I expect it to put a `where` clause in the sql, but, it gives me this with no `where` clause:

```sql
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Extent1].[ClientId] AS [ClientId], 
    [Extent1].[Version] AS [Version], 
    [Extent1].[ReferenceNumber] AS [ReferenceNumber], 
    [Extent1].[RealExpirationDate] AS [RealExpirationDate], 
    [Extent1].[BusinessEffectiveDate] AS [BusinessEffectiveDate], 
    [Extent1].[BusinessExpirationDate] AS [BusinessExpirationDate], 
    [Extent1].[IsSuspended] AS [IsSuspended], 
    [Extent1].[RealEffectiveDate] AS [RealEffectiveDate], 
    [Extent1].[User] AS [User],
    [Extent1].[Category] AS [Category]
    FROM [dbo].[YouTube] AS [Extent1]
```

This is going to be a big problem with large tables. How can I change it to create the `where` clause?

Comment: Few EF posts before yours - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42585640/entity-framework-lambda-predicate-stored-in-var-with-association. Shortly, change `Func<...>` to `Expression<Func<...>>`

Comment: @IvanStoev, how can I wrap the predicate in an expression if I don't want to change the signature?

Comment: You can't. `Expression<Func<...>>` can be converted to `Func<...>` by using the `Compile` method, but not vice versa. This is because `Expression` is more abstract (expression tree) which can be converted to code, to string or in your case - to SQL. `Func` is just a code that can be executed.

Comment: Note that from the caller side they look similar (in most of the cases). You can still use `Select('sdfsdf', o => o.Category == 'Save Pewdiepie')` after changing the signature :)

Comment: @IvanStoev, do you want to answer, or do you want me to delete this duplicate question? The only thing unique about my question is I asked it in a more layman's terminology. My original search didn't find existing articles because they were terminology laden.

Comment: It's up to you mate, I'm not planning to post an answer. It's all about if your code calls `Queryable` or `Enumerable` extension method with the same name. Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix it by using `Expression` as so:

```
public IEnumerable<T> Select(string sessionId, Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate = null)
{
  using (var databaseContext = new DatabaseContext())
  {
    var list = databaseContext.Set<T>().Where(predicate ?? (x => true)).ToList();
    list.ForEach(o => o.SessionId = sessionId);
    return list;
  }
}
```